# USB Tethering only SOMETIMES working

Tags: xiaomi, tethering

Hello unlike all the problems here which is related to their USB Tethering in android being grayed out or not working at all when connected, mine is an odd case

I use usb tethering with my android Xiaomi Mi9 since my PC doesn't have LAN and the wifi dongle reads my wifi as "Hidden Network" and inputting SSID still doesn't work

I can toggle on and off USB Tethering but the tethering doesn't work all the time. There are times where I tether and it gives my PC internet. There are also times where nothing happens even though my tethering is turned on and i have to turn it on and off multiple times until it does.

Now It's even worse because i have to on-off it multiple times like 5-10 times already.

I didn't use USB debugging and I don't have any VPN applications
I tried using a different wire and it's still the same.

Can anyone give me insight on what the problem might be?

Answer (score 0):

Need to narrow it down a bit, potentially three items assuming that your phone network operator is not at fault

Phone itself

Data cable

The PC

Can you if possible try your phone and cable on a different PC.

Do you have any data transfer issues with the phone on the PC ? such as backups etc,  worth trying another cable if possible.

Daft one but try the cable in a different USB port too.

Finally if you are able to try a different phone on your PC to test if tethering works.

It may not matter but others could need to know what OS your PC is running.